# Extracting Arabic Proper Names from a text using Stanford-Parser

Tags: text-parsing, arabic, stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract Arabic proper names from a text using Stanford Parser.

for example if I have an input sentence:

```
تكريم سعد الدين الشاذلى
```

using the Arabic Stanford parser, the tree diagram will be:

```
(ROOT (NP (NN تكريم) (NP (NNP سعد) (DTNNP الدين) (NNP الشاذلى))))
```

I want to extract the proper name:

```
سعد الدين الشاذلى
```

which have the sub-tree:

```
(NP (NNP سعد) (DTNNP الدين) (NNP الشاذلى))
```

I have tried this: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044354/extracting-all-nouns-adjectives-form-a-text-via-stanford-parser)

but there is some thing wrong in this line:

```
List<TaggedWord> taggedWords = (Tree) lp.apply(str);
```

the error in putting a tree type in a list of taggedword
another thing that I didnot understand that where could i use the suggested  `taggedYield()`  function

Any Ideas, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty basic Java with respect to the library, but what you want is:

```
Tree tree = lp.apply(str);
List<TaggedWord> taggedWords = tree.taggedYield();
for (TaggedWord tw : taggedWords) {
  if (tw.tag().contains("NNP")) {
    System.err.println(tw.word());
  }
}
```