# Name Entity Recognition for Arabic documents

Tags: stanford-nlp

I need your help please, I am doing **NER** project using **NetBeans v.8.0.2**.

I need to get the **Person Names** and **Places** out of any Arabic document-file and categorize them as person name, Place. I saw all *Stanford files*, *POS tagger*, *parser* and also *Stanford NER*. And I tried them all, the tagger works fine with me.

But i had problems with Parser especially in this line of code

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(grammar, options);
```

from **ParserDemo** and no output comes up. Do i need the parser first to tokenize the document then to use POS tagger, or i can just use the POS tagger with some editing (like using if statement to combine all NNP together and the same for places).

Answer (score 1):

So first of all as of the moment we do not have any Arabic NER models.

Secondly, I'll post some steps for running the Stanford parser on Arabic text.

1. Get the Stanford parser: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml
2. Compile ParserDemo.java ; you need the jars present in the directory stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20 to compile
3. I ran this command at the command line while in the stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20 directory, (do the analogous thing in NetBeans):

java -cp ".:*" ParserDemo edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/arabicFactored.ser.gz data/arabic-onesent-utf8.txt

You should get a proper parse of the Arabic example sentence.

So when you run ParserDemo in NetBeans, make sure you provide "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/arabicFactored.ser.gz" as the first argument to ParserDemo , so it knows to load the Arabic model.

For this input:

```
و نشر العدل من خلال قضاء مستقل
```

I get this output:

```
(ROOT
  (S (CC و)
    (VP (VBD نشر)
      (NP (DTNN العدل))
      (PP (IN من)
        (NP (NN خلال)
          (NP (NN قضاء) (JJ مستقل)))))
    (PUNC .)))
```

I am happy to help you further, please let me know if you need any more info.

FYI here is some more info on the Arabic parser:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-arabic-faq.shtml

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks a lot for your helpful answer. I did all that before i ask the question, and i read all FAQs for all NER, Parser,Segmenter,... etc. I tried the trained data that you mentioned in your example and it's worked with me fine, but the problem is when you need a full name for the same person such as ( ذهب سعد الدين علي الى الجامعة )  since (سعد الدين علي) is the name for one person. The result (ROOT  (S  (VP (VBD ذهب)
      (NP (NNP سعد) (DTNNP الدين) (NNP علي))
      (PP (IN الى)
        (NP (DTNN الجامعة)))))) ,

Comment: I saw the article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505569/extracting-arabic-proper-names-from-a-text-using-stanford-parser) i tried the same but it didn't work. what i need is: the compound names in Arabic to be joint to each other such as (عبد الله) ، (محمد بن راشد). Another question: in Parser for English language, there is something called(GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();) is there the same at Arabic. Many thanks a gain for your help. I really appreciate that.